# VSCode Clangd extension wrong function argument type annotation

Tags: visual-studio-code, clangd

For some reason, Clang is showing five x type annotations (lines 24 & 25) and I don't know why, shouldn't be just one?

[image: Source]

It is not so bad in this example, but it gets annoying with larger expressions.

I want to know why is this happening

Comment: What clangd version are you using?

Comment: clang version 14.0.6

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to check because clangd 13 and older was affected by a known issue related to duplication of inlay hints, which was fixed in clangd 14. Since you're using clangd 14, you may be running into another bug that hasn't been reported yet. Please consider reporting it [here](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=).